# How to avoid using Convert.ToDateTime?

Tags: c#

I need to read in the two dates but I havev been told not to use ConvertToDateTime(Console.ReadLine), What else can I do here ? 
Sample:

**input** 
13/11/2020 
24 December 2020
 
**output**

41 days

```
DateTime start = Convert.ToDateTime(Console.ReadLine());
DateTime end = Convert.ToDateTime(Console.ReadLine());
TimeSpan difference = end - start;
Console.WriteLine(difference.Days);
```

Comment: You reading from console mean can user enter date in any format?

Comment: Yeah, can be only numbers or it can be like 24 december 2020

Comment: *"can be only numbers"* can you update your question with sample input data which can come through?

Comment: I did it can be the other way around as well! like input
23 November 2020
23/11/2021
output
365 days

Answer (score 0):

Use DateTime.Parse, see example in Microsoft docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=net-6.0#System_DateTime_Parse_System_String_

Comment: `DateTime.TryParse()` would be better in case the user enters something like "this is not a date".

Comment: While this post does answer the question, please consider [edit]ing some more detail (such as an example) into your answer to protect against link-rot.